# Access to stye.css denied - Django Static files - Nginx - I can't make my project read staticfiles (style.css)

Tags: django, nginx, django-templates, nginx-config, django-staticfiles

I don't know what it could be anymore, I've already given permissions to the files, directories, reviewed the nginx config, the files in sites-available/enabled , I've already cleared the cache through django-shell , I've restarted the instance. I simply don't know.

Here is the output of nginx:

sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2024/03/28 02:27:01 [error] 2952#2952: *12 open() "/home/ubuntu/learning-app/learning-log/learningLog/staticfiles/learningLogApp/css/estilo.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 179.214.112.55, server: django.xxx.dev, request: "GET /static/learningLogApp/css/estilo.css HTTP/1.1", host: "django.xxx.dev", referrer: "https://django.xxx.dev/assuntos/"
```

nginx.config:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {



    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;


    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;



    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;



    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;



    gzip on;



    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

sites-available

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name django.xxx.dev;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/django.xxx.dev/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/django.xxx.dev/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/learning-app/learning-log/learningLog/staticfiles;
    }
    # Redirecionamento de HTTP para HTTPS
    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

what have I tried

```
sudo chmod -R a+r /home/ubuntu/learning-app/learning-log/learningLog/staticfiles
```

```
sudo find /home/ubuntu/learning-app/learning-log/learningLog/staticfiles -type d -exec chmod a+x {} +
```

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/ubuntu/learning-app/learning-log/learningLog/staticfiles
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/ubuntu/learning-app/learning-log/learningLog/staticfiles
```

django shell

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.clear()
```

=( I don't know what else to try

Comment: Have you run [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic)?

Comment: Yes..nothing to update

Answer (score 0):

I got it guys.. first I checked the directory permissions with

```
namei -l /home/ubuntu/learning-app/learning-log/learningLog/staticfiles/learningLogApp/css/estilo.css
```

```
drwxr-xr-x root     root     /
drwxr-xr-x root     root     home
drwxr-x--- ubuntu   ubuntu   ubuntu
drwxr-xr-x ubuntu   ubuntu   learning-app
drwxr-xr-x ubuntu   ubuntu   learning-log
drwxr-xr-x ubuntu   ubuntu   learningLog
drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data staticfiles
drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data learningLogApp
drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data css
-rwxr-xr-x www-data www-data estilo.css
```

and then...

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/ubuntu
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Jezz...=P I knew it was something simple lol